# need to define a single that overlays another line to create a X for my tic tac toe game

Tags: line, racket, tic-tac-toe

I am using Racket to draw a line to overlay another line to create a x for the tictactoe game.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
;part1 draws a  circle
(define (singlecircle)(circle 20 "outline" (pensetup "red" 3)))

;part1.2 defines omark, overlays singlecircle on top of the whitebox using voerlay function
(define (omark) (overlay (singlecircle)(whitebox)))

;part1.3 calls omark, will draw a single red circle
(omark)



;part2.1
(define (singleline)(line 30 30 "blue"))
;part2.2

(define (flipsingleline)(flip-horizontal -30 (singleine "blue" -30)))

;part2.3
(define (xlines)(overlay (singleline)(flipsingleine)))

;part2.4
(define (xmark)(overlay (xlines)(whitebox)))
(xmark)



;part3

(define (wholeboard)
  (beside (omark)(omark)(omark))
(above (omark)(omark)(omark)))
```